# Allow user inteaction with UITextField in a CollectionView Cell

Tags: ios

I've written an IOS App which uses `UITableViewCells` and I am converting it to use `UICollectionView Cells`.

It's working OK at present, but I can't figure out how to allow user to update a `UITextFied` which is situated within the `UICollectionView Cell`.

I've managed to do this with `UITableView Cells`.

I've searched for answers to my problem, but can't find anything that uses a `UITextField` within a `UICollectionView Cell`.
Help in pointing me in the right direction would be much appreiciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show us some of the code you are using. I have used UITextFields in UICollectionViews without a problem, so I am not sure what your question is.

Edit:

First add a tag in storyboard or programatically to your textfield for this example we will use a tag of 2

Then every time you want to modify the textfield simply call

```
UITextField *myText = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
```

Comment: Its basically the example code from Apple for Collection Views. I just added a UITextField to the Cell. But I don't know how to access it from outside the Collection View methods.

Comment: Tried that but it only recognises cell within collection view methods. Outside these methods I get - use of undeclared identifier 'cell'.

Comment: Then you will want to use Ivan's code above as that provides the proper way to access your cell from outside the scope of the cell delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare and IBOutlet for the UITextField and then get it lkike that:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:some_index_path];
UITextField *myTextField = cell.textFieldOutlet;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It's work for me,

First you have to set tag to `UITextFied`

[image: set tag to uitextfield]

Add below line of code :-

```
   -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITextField *addCaptionTxt=(UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    [cell addSubview:addCaptionTxt];
    return cell;
 }
```